# Why does OAuth2 support grant_type=password?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

I've seen several API's using OAuth 2.0 for authentication that use the password grant_type. I find this a bit confusing because:

A huge advantage of the typical OAuth 2 model is that the application never needs to handle the user's username/password for the service being connected to. Grant type password loses this advantage so I'm not sure why you use it over Basic authentication, especially since basic at least encodes the credentials while you send them as plain text with grant type password.

What am I missing that makes this kind of OAuth a valid use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the official name is Resource Owner Password Credentials grant; it is meant as a migration mechanism only, not a primary OAuth 2.0 flow since OAuth was indeed designed to mitigate the issues of entering user credentials in a client application; see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.7

it allows the Resource Server to migrate to OAuth 2.0 by accepting and validating access tokens, the client can later be upgraded to a grant that allows for better security

Answer (score 2):

There is a valid and important use case for the password grant_type, and not just for legacy systems: `grant_type=password` is a great way to implement official, first-party applications. That way you can use the same oauth2 authorization servers for both first-party and third-party applications.

It's an example of API-first design, in which your own apps are built against the same APIs you expose for use by third-party apps.